# SQLAlchemy with pymssql slash in server name

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, database-connection

I am currently trying to make my connection string for SQLAlchemy to MSSQL configurable. From my testing, this works:

```
engine = create_engine("mssql+pymssql://username:password@dviserver\dev0000/db").connect()
```

However, how do I enter the port number into this connection string, I've tried the following and it does not work:

```
engine = create_engine("mssql+pymssql://username:password@dviserver\dev0000:1433/db").connect()
```

Below is the stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src\pymssql.pyx", line 636, in pymssql.connect
  File "src\_mssql.pyx", line 1957, in _mssql.connect
  File "src\_mssql.pyx", line 677, in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.__init__
_mssql.MSSQLDriverException: Connection to the database failed for an unknown reason.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\conda\publisher-app\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2158, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "C:\conda\publisher-app\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 342, in unique_connection
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "C:\conda\publisher-app\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 788, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "C:\conda\publisher-app\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 529, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "C:\conda\publisher-app\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 1193, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "C:\conda\publisher-app\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 66, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "C:\conda\publisher-app\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 249, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\conda\publisher-app\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 1190, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "C:\conda\publisher-app\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 347, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "C:\conda\publisher-app\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 474, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "C:\conda\publisher-app\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 671, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "C:\conda\publisher-app\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 106, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\conda\publisher-app\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 412, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "src\pymssql.pyx", line 645, in pymssql.connect
pymssql.InterfaceError: Connection to the database failed for an unknown reason.
```

Comment: what error are you getting exactly?

Comment: I had a similar issue, not sure about the server you are trying to connect, but sometimes the PORT number is not accepted as part of the SERVER part

Have you tried passing it as a parameter?

    engine = create_engine("mssql+pymssql://username:password@dviserver\dev0000/db?port=1433").connect()

Comment: @SaulCruz tried adding port as a parameter, did not work, got the same exception :(

Comment: which exception are you getting @LeBron James

Comment: @SaulCruz I've pasted the stack trace above, "pymssql.InterfaceError: Connection to the database failed for an unknown reason."